# C# Problems with XML Serialization

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap, xamarin.android

i have a problem with a webservice but i don´t see the error. I have used a wsdl to generate the Web Reference in VS2017. This is the class which was generated:

https://gist.github.com/meteora1986/b43c9750ddeb50187420edd6741301f5

When using this class the xml used for the webservice is not generated with the XMLAttributes-options. While debugging i discoverd following errors by the XMLImporter:
[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9LWU.png)

So i tried to serialize it to get a more detailed error message with code like

```
try 
{         
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ari_webserviceService));   
}
catch (Exception ex) 
{
    // codes    
}
```

And got from from the exeption these messages:
1. inner Message: There was an error reflecting field 'Site'.
2. inner MessageThere was an error reflecting type 'System.ComponentModel.ISite'.

But these fields or types aren´t used in the webservice class? Can anybody help?

Comment: Why are you trying to serialize your service class? What are you trying to achieve and what is the problem?

Comment: I just tried to get a more specified error message. I don’t serialize it for any other purpose.

Comment: I just tried to get a more specified error message. I don’t serialize it for any other purpose.               When I use the web service the xml which is send is not the xml it should be. The xml attributes e.g. object names are ignored. For example the object “ixml” should be named  “i.xml” but that isn’t working for all the objects. It seems that all commands like this are ignored: “[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(...)]”. But I don’t know why and that’s the problem...

Answer (score 0):

I have absolutly no idea of web-services in general.

But your webservice is derived from `SoapHttpClientProtocol`. If you go up the base-classes by `HttpWebClientProtocol` and `WebClientProtocol` to finally end with `Component` you'll see the property `Component.Site`.

You *might* be able to solve your problem if you implement the `IXmlSerializable` interface to have full control what (and how) you want to serialize the data...

Comment: Thanks, I haven’t seen that. I think it was the wrong way to serialize the whole class of the web service for debugging purposes. but I try to implement IXmlSerializable, thank you for you advice!